# Solve $\log_{1/4}{x}=\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, logarithms

I want to solve $$\log_{1/4}{x}=\frac{3}{2}$$
Now I know the result is: $$\frac{1}{8}$$ but I am not sure how to get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\implies x=\left(\dfrac14\right)^{3/2}=\left(\dfrac1{2^2}\right)^{3/2}=(2^{-2})^{-3/2}=2^{-3}=\dfrac1{2^3}$$

Comment: oh, yeah, I am stupid, I see it now, so simple, thanks :)

Comment: @Mykybo, Welcome!  See also : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws

Answer (score 0):

Other way $$(1/4)^{3/2}=\sqrt{1/4}^3=\sqrt{1/64}=\pm 1/8$$ but we have log so $x=1/8$

Comment: Your answer should be $\frac{1}{8}$.  Note that $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^x > 0$ for any real number $x$.  Also, the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ refers to the principal (nonnegative) square root of $x$, so $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{64}} = \frac{1}{8}$$   To indicate the negative square root, we write $-\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (I only know Naperian logarithms) $$\log_{1/4}{(x)}=-\frac{\log (x)}{\log (4)}=\frac{3}{2}$$ so $$\log(x)=-\frac{3}{2}\log (4)=-3\log (2)=-\log(2^3)=-\log(8)=\log(\frac18)$$